# Excel VBA export CSV with path/filename taken from cell in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have the following code which saves the active sheet in a workbook to a csv file

```
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Range("T1").Value & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

the filename is taken from cell T1 in the active sheet. I would like to specify the filename in a different sheet -- say cell A2 in Sheets("path")

I have searched for the answer, but I can't find how to reference it correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Workbooks(nameOfWorkbook).Sheets(nameOfSheet).Range("T1").Value & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

Where

```
nameOfWorkbook
nameOfSheet
```

are strings like "myWorkbook" and "Sheet2"

If you want a sheet in the current workbook, you could use

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(...)
```

or even

```
Sheets(...)
```

since the default is "this one". But I highly recommend being explicit - with VBA you never know...

Comment: Thanks very much! Your code with ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(...) allowed me to do what I needed -- much appreciated...

Comment: @user2904588 glad it was helpful. Welcome to SO! I hope you will come back from time to time and try to answer questions as well as ask them - this is a site that exists because we all contribute. Since you are new, you might want to check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/212464)